# Having trouble loading rJava and xlsx on R studio keep getting same error message

Tags: java, r, xlsx, rjava

Hello I am attempting to export some R files that were edited in R to excel. I am trying to install the package xlsx and rjava as they both are needed.

I have already tried to download Java into the file pathway but it will not let me since the folder already has files in it. So I did the next best thing and created a folder in hopes this would work but I keep getting the same error. I also have Rtools installed.

```
> install.packages("rJava")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Austin/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/rJava_0.9-11.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 832080 bytes (812 KB)
downloaded 812 KB

package ‘rJava’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Austin\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpcHsZaF\downloaded_packages
> library("rJava")
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
  error: unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/Austin/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/rJava/libs/x64/rJava.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.
```

Being able to export R files to excel

Comment: So I did remove file 00LOCK and that did not change anything also I tried to unzip that file it also did not change anything

Comment: Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_144") tried this code and it did not help

Comment: options(java.home="C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_65\\jre")
install.packages("rJava")
install.packages("XLConnect")
install.packages("XLConnectJars")
library(rJava)
library(XLConnect)
library(XLConnectJars) I attempted this code as well did not work

Comment: Hi Austin,
I head a similar problem a few months ago. It made me crazy. Anyway my solution was to install R independent from RStudio and install the packages. Hope this will help you too.

Comment: Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME='C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre7') # for 64-bit version
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME='C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre7') # for 32-bit version
library(rJava) Also attempted this code it did not help as well

Comment: Hello Johannes yes that is about the point I am at when you say install them independent of each other do you mean that you download both R and Rstudio because I did do that as well.

Comment: I use openxlsx. It is based on c++ rather than Java and I've found it to be a lot more stable.

Comment: Yes, exactly. But I see now that I missed that you use Windows not Mac.

Comment: Oh that is okay thank you for trying Johannes. Imo, i attempted that as well and got the same error

Comment: I have an online PC with Windows10 64. I tried to install `xlsx`package same error and found this solution [https://cimentadaj.github.io/blog/2018-05-25-installing-rjava-on-windows-10/installing-rjava-on-windows-10/]. and changed `Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-10.0.1/")` to `jdk-12.0.2`

Comment: hmmmm tried that out but still nothing I will look in my folders to see if mabye it has a different name

Comment: I am going to take a break on this